# Debugging Time in PHP

Tags: php

OK so I have been through several other Q&A sections of this site looking for the information pertaining to my PhP validation problem which I am having. I am trying to validate that a user input time is A) in a valid given time format, and B) a valid time to begin with. Here is the code which I am using (including the HTML section of the form)

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
        $timeerror = "Current Time is required";
    } else {
        $time = test_input($_POST["time"]);
        if (!preg_match("/(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9])/i", $time)) {
            $timeerror = "Time must be in HH:MM format";
        }
    }
}

<input type="text" size="6" name="time" id="time" title="Enter current time" required><?php echo $timeerror; ?><br>
```

When I input a time such as 06:30 or even 6:30 it returns the error "Time must be in HH:MM format". This is very frustrating as this form is supposed to be being published in about 2 weeks and there are still a lot of these types of debugging issues which I still need to sort out.

Comment: Validate the time using inbuilt `DateTime` class. Why complicate? Also, if you want maintainable project, use a framework and structure the code so  that you don't end up with cabbage like you have now.

Comment: Really depends more on what your `test_input()` call leaves over as `$time`. Your regex itself would also permit `xyz000000:5999999whatever` btw; because it's not anchored.

Comment: @N.B. That might be useful if the "time stamp" being entered was supposed to be the current time of submission however this form allows for the user to enter a time earlier in the day from when the form is submitted.

Comment: And here I thought that you could create datetime from any format.. silly me, reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reg-ex is wrong.

Change to this reg-ex to validate time in HH:MM format:

```
/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

The ^ states that this is the start, and $ states this is the end, so only "2 digits:2 digits" input will be accepted. The time checking itself is OK.